# バイナリデータの中の\\Zの意味

Tags: バイナリファイル

バイナリファイルをPythonで読もうとしているのですが、
下記のようなバイナリデータを見つけました

```
\x96\x08\\Z\xbbf\xd0g\t\x93
```

このバイナリデータの中で、\Zはエスケープシーケンスの一つだと思うのですが、
これはどのような意味のエスケープシーケンスなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

`\\Z`の部分は`\\`と`Z`でそれぞれ1バイトを表しています。

`\\` -> `\x5c`
`Z` -> `\x5a`

ASCIIの表示文字に対応するバイトは(エスケープ文字の`\`を除いて)エスケープ形式でなく、コードの表す文字そのままで表示されています。